# how can I solve this params errors in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**I have a react project and I want to send params with Route**

[image]

my HomeScreen.js page is ok but when I open a product *ProductScreen.js* page is has **noting**

pls help me i realy need ur herp i am working on this like 2 days and i cant find the way

this is my app.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeScreen from './screeens/HomeScreen'
import ProductScreen from './screeens/ProductScreen'
function App() {
  return (<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="grid-container">
      <header className="row">
        <div>
          <a className="brand" href="/">MRshop</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="/cart">Cart</a>
          <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} ></Route>
          <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} exact></Route>
        </Routes>
      </main>
      <footer className="row center">All right reserved</footer>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**and this is my ProductScreen.js code**

```
import React from "react"
import Rating from "../components/Rating"
import data from "../data"
import params from "react-router-dom";
export default function ProductScreen(props) {
    const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === props.match.params.id);
    if (!product) {
        return <div>product not found</div>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-2'>
                    <img className="large" src={product.img} alt={product.name} />
                </div>
                <div className='col-1'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{product.name}</li>
                        <li><Rating
                            rating={product.rating}
                            numReviews={product.numReviews}>
                        </Rating>
                        </li>
                        <li> Price: {product.price}</li>
                        <li> Description: <p> {product.description}</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='col-1'>
                    <div className="card card-body ">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div>price</div>
                                    <div className="price">{product.price}</div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div>status</div>
                                    <div>{product.countInStock > 0 ? (
                                        <span className="success">In Stock</span>
                                    ) : (
                                        <span className="error">unavailable </span>
                                    )}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button className="primary block">Add to Cart</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer any route props, i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match`, instead they are replaced by React hooks. `props.match` is undefined and throws an error when trying to then access `props.match.params`.

- `history` object replaced by a `navigate` function via `useNavigation`
- `location` object via `useLocation`
- `match` via a `useMatch` hook, but `params` object via `useParams` was added in v6

The `useParams` hook is what you want to access the `id` route param.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

export default function ProductScreen() {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const product = data.products.find((x) => String(x._id) === id);

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using the switch import from react-dom

`

```html
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
 </Switch>
```

2. For retrieving the params from another page

const { id } = useParams<{ id?: string }>();

Comment: The `Switch` is a RRDv5 component, it was removed in RRDv6.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).